# Docker image giving Timeout after 300 seconds

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda

I am testing a AWS lambda docker image on Local computer and if the process is under 5min/300 sec, it runs smoothly, and if the time limit approaches 300 sec, it gives timeout error. I haven't set any time limit anywhere.
Here's my docker script:

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.9
ENV GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS cloud_vision_api/vision-api.json


RUN yum install git -y
RUN yum update -y && yum install amazon-linux-extras -y && PYTHON=python2 amazon-linux-extras install epel -y && yum update -y && yum install git-lfs -y
RUN git lfs install

COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD [ "handler.handle_response"]
```

And here's the timeout error:

```
25 Oct 2023 05:56:18,129 [WARNING] (rapid) Reset initiated: Timeout
25 Oct 2023 05:56:18,130 [INFO] (rapid) Sending SIGKILL to runtime-1(14).
25 Oct 2023 05:56:18,155 [INFO] (rapid) Stopping runtime domain
25 Oct 2023 05:56:18,155 [INFO] (rapid) Waiting for runtime domain processes termination
25 Oct 2023 05:56:18,155 [INFO] (rapid) Stopping operator domain
25 Oct 2023 05:56:18,155 [INFO] (rapid) Starting runtime domain
END RequestId: 9501e4ef-f121-4385-9345-30e27825b70b
REPORT RequestId: 9501e4ef-f121-4385-9345-30e27825b70b  Duration: 300000.00 ms  Billed Duration: 300000 ms      Memory Size: 3008 MB    Max Memory Used: 3008 MB
```

Comment: "You can now configure your AWS Lambda functions to run up to 15 minutes per execution. Previously, the maximum execution time (timeout) for a Lambda function was 5 minutes.", from - https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/10/aws-lambda-supports-functions-that-can-run-up-to-15-minutes/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For testing on local, pass in the env variable AWS_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_TIMEOUT, in the docker file. For example, to set the docker time out of 10 min,

```
ENV AWS_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_TIMEOUT="600"
```

After this, built the docker image again and run it.